# Get manufacturer name in android device

Tags: android, hardware

I need to check that android device's manufacturer is dell or not.
But I haven't dell device, so cant get actually name of manufacture of device(for dell).

I'm using `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;`
Does anyone know  that what is the value returned for the above query in case of a dell device?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here is the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices) link about Android devices and MANUFACTURER strings.

EDIT: That Wikipedia page has been deleted. [Here](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/55CB98F98AF3955A49708F44F2CA562858E2) is a PDF list from Google Play which lists all supported devices and their manufacturers.

Comment: I have HTC device and I get manufacturer name is HTC but the name of HTC mobile's manufacturer is "HTC Corporation" as per yr URL.

Comment: Take the string and just check if it contains the first name. Like HTC, DELL, samsung etc etc.

Comment: now i m checking with "DELL" but i cant confirm it bcz i cant able to check in DELL device.

Comment: Ignore case while checking. You can check when you get a test device. Just remember to do that :), may be put a TODO at this place.

Comment: That wikipedia page has been deleted as of 7 October 2014

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```